# How can i find out what feature of android google has used in creating its google notes?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I recently started developing apps and i started with a notes app. I have designed all the functionality and now I am trying to implement the best features in it . Then i looked at google keep app .

In google keep notes app when we create a new notes  ,they are dynamically placed somewhere . We can easily pin the notes at the top or we can change the color of a particular notes .How can i achieve that? I wonder if they had used fragments that has an editview or any other component that iam not aware of . I want to use such features in my app .

so my question is ,how do i dynamically drag and place my new notes and also how can i change each notes background?
can i achieve that using fragments?
Thankyou
Thank you :)

Comment: only Google knows for sure what they used. We can only guess, and this is wrong place to ask for guesses. If you have some specific question (like how to implement dragging of views, how to change color, etc) be more specific and ask them.

Comment: okay i want to know how to create such functionality .Is it possible by using fagments?

Comment: I think it is, but it is too simple to use fragments for it.